# XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: javascript, cors

I add an API with following script in let's say http://www.test.com:

```
<script src="http://apiendpoint.com/api/v1/api.js"></script>

<div id="api" data-apikey="LA59CJI9HZ-KIJK4I5-3CKJC"></div>
```

**api.js**

```
$(function () {

  apikey = $('#api').data('apikey');
  $("#api").load("http://apiendpoint.com?apikey=" + apikey);

})
```

When I load the page, I get following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   **apiendpoint URL**.
>   Redirect from
>   '**apiendpoint URL**' to
>   '**apiendpoint URL**' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   '**test URL**' is therefore not allowed access.

In the path of apiendpoint.com I added in .htaccess following code:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Check using your browser tools network tab to verify that the header is present

Comment: Also Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Download CORS plugin from chrome store and try making a request after turning it on.

Comment: @Ferrybig The response header don't contain "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*". But when i load the URL directly it contains the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Comment: @codeslayer1 I already downloaded the plugin and it works, but this is not the solution

Comment: Check the request type, the first request is an Options request, this one should also contain the header (and you may need to allow options requests in apache)

Comment: I believe [sideshowbarker 's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/7886100) will have all the info you need to fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 14):

I believe [sideshowbarker 's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/7886100) has all the info you need to fix this. If your problem is just No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the response you're getting, you can set up a CORS proxy to get around this. Way more info on it in the linked answer

Answer (score 5):

I know this might be late, but hope this will help others. This problem comes from backend side, call CORS. I'm using java for backend so I added`@CrossOrigin` to `Controller` class. It works!